# PHP foreach loop where two values are compared

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm building a simple weight log, where there'a table that display the user's progress. I'm using Codeigniter.

```
    <?php foreach($logs as $log) : ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $log->date ;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $log->weight ;?> kg.</td>
        <td><!-- variation between this record and previous record. weigth[a] - weight[b] --></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo anchor('logs/edit/'.$log->id, 'Editar'); ?> <?php echo anchor('logs/delete/'.$log->id, 'Delete'); ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ;?>
```

I'm trying to calculate the variation between the first row and the second row, so as to get the weight loss or gain between logs. I was wondering how to access the loop's previous record so as to substract it from the current record's weight.

```
---------------------------------------
  DATE     |   WEIGHT  |   VARIATION
---------------------------------------
  Nov 20   |    70 kg  |     -1 kg      << LAST LOGGED WEIGHT, FIRST IN ARRAY
.......................................
  Nov 15   |    71 kg  |      -
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: Added a quick representation of the loop's result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One simple way to do it:

```
<?php $previousWeight = null; ?>
<?php foreach($logs as $log) : ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
        <?php
            if ($previousWeight) {
                echo $previousWeight - $log->weight;
            }
            $previousWeight = $log->weight;
        ?>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

---

Or, the reverse way:

```
<?php
    $current = current($logs);
    $next = next($logs);
?>
<?php while ($current) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $current->date; ?></td>
        ...
        <td>
            <?php
                if ($next) {
                    echo $current->weight - $next->weight;
                }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $current = $next;
        $next = next($logs);
    ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If your array keys are guaranteed to be numeric (which they probably are), this can be simplified a lot. See [@William's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129714/php-foreach-loop-where-two-values-are-compared/4129741#4129741).

Comment: It seems to be working, though the first variation in the table is blank when it shouldn't be. The last variation of the table should be blank since there's no previous weight to compare it to. It's like the variation column ought to have some kind of offset.

Comment: @Landitus Sorry, I don't get it. If you want to compare to the previous record, of course the *first* line will be blank, since the *first* line has no *previous* record... Can you clarify what exactly you want?

Comment: I guess my confusion comes with the array, which is sorted by date in a way the last logged weight is the first value of the table (or the array). So the last logged weight is at the top and has a key value of 0. that means the first logged weight is at the bottom of the table and that's why it shouldn't have a variation value (nor previous weight)

Comment: Sorry @deceze, but $current->any gets errors cause I only have $logs. Is it a Codeigniter thing? The 'while' replaces a 'for each loop'? Or I have to nest them? Sorry for not getting it!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the while thing, but know I do! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `key => value` option for `foreach` ([here](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)). This would give you the current index in the log, so finding the previous index would be `index = ($key == 0) ? $key : ($key - 1); $old_weight = $logs[$index];` (the syntax might be a bit off, but the idea is there).

Comment: Your answer assumes consecutive numeric indexes. Which is probably the case (given code sample) but is worth making explicit.

Comment: I'm trying this approach as well the one provided by deceze (which looks clearer to me at first).